# JasperReports - Splitting a band's background frame

Tags: jasper-reports

Though my company's system creates the reports dynamically, I could manually reduce my scenario to this:
- **Two details bands**, with a bunch of static texts in them;
- **A frame object** in the second band, so I can create a background filling the whole band;

**My main problem:** when the second band reaches de end of the page and breaks to the next one, the background frame is printed in it's whole height. A sample screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, the band's beginning doesn't print the frame (because of it's height) and it is printed with his whole height in the second page, **pushing the second text label down**. That is basically my problem: the frame background pushes the text of the bands that overflow the page.

I've played **a lot** with the properties, and nothing yet. For the band, I'm using **Stretch** split type (and tried **Immediate**); for the frame, I tried combining **Print When Detail Overflows** with **Print Repeated Values**, changed the height and Stretch Type to **Relative to Band Height** or **Relative to Tallest Object**. Nothing yet.

PS: Due to the dynamic nature of the software, using **Float** position type is not an option, since we must offer the option of setting the text's **Top** property to the client.

I'll be really thankful if someone has any idea if this is even possible with JasperReports.

Comment: As far as I know the solution is (if not enough space make it start on new page) or set background to the textElements.

Comment: @PetterFriberg Since the bands are too broad, we couldn't push them to the next page because the space would be too wide. The background on text elements would be nicer, but since the client is able to set the Y position of the labels, there could be gaps.

It's kind of a dead end, I guess, but thank you for your considerations!

Comment: Try to remove the frame, and add <rectangle> as background with stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight".

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's what we were using before, so people told us to use frame instead. I didn't get any difference yet, but I'll try to explore a bit more of the rectangle flow